# How do I correctly implement Immersive Full-Screen Mode in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-immersive

I have an application where I have a single activity that contains layers of fragments. I wanted to Switch between Immersive mode and Normal mode during some states of the app. Everything was fine until I call Hide System UI as per [Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html)

[image: Documentation Code]

The sizes of the fragments started to go weird. No solutions found in stack overflow was any help.

I have uploaded the project to [GitHub](https://github.com/cocoBavan/ImmersiveTest) . Could you please provide some insights on what I am doing wrong?

1. Project When Started 
   [image: Step One]
2. When another Fragment was added to the same FrameLayout

[image: Step Two]

3. When Third fragment was added to another FrameLayout while Immersive mode is triggered

[image: Step 3]

4. Problem begins When Third Fragment's View minimised we trigger "Normal Mode". The top and bottom of the Previous fragments were cut out.
   [image: Step 4]

Moreover, Go Full Screen, Rotate and then Tap tap on PIP. It gets more ugly.

I have uploaded the project to [GitHub](https://github.com/cocoBavan/ImmersiveTest) . Could you please provide some insights on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```
public void showSystemUI() {
        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();

        if (decorView != null) {
            decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE  | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            );
        }
}
```

makes it better, but there are still issues with  Status bar & Nested View Sizes.